# MongoDB C# Driver - Model for aggregation lookup field

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB C# Driver and I came across a problem on a model with a lookup field. The models are like this:

```cs
public class Product
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public int Price { get; set; }

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I perform an aggregation lookup to include the `Category` on `Product` result:

```cs
var products = productsCollection
                .Aggregate()
                .Match(Builders<Product>.Filter.Where(_ => true))
                .Lookup(categoriesCollection,
                        p => p.CategoryId,
                        c => c.Id,
                        (Product p) => p.Category)
                .Unwind(p => p.Category, new AggregateUnwindOptions<Product>() { PreserveNullAndEmptyArrays = true })
                .ToList();
```

The result looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "Id": "6207eafaef1ae25be4c731b3",
    "Price": 250,
    "CategoryId": "6207eadbef1ae25be4c731b0",
    "Category": {
      "Id": "6207eadbef1ae25be4c731b0",
      "Name": "Books"
    }
  }
]
```

---

The problem came on `Product` insertion:

```cs
var product = new Product()
{
    Price = 750,
    CategoryId = "6207eadbef1ae25be4c731b0"
};
productsCollection.InsertOne(product);
```

The `Category` field is also stored along with other fields inside the collection.

[image: Result in MongoDB Compass]

I fixed this problem by adding `BsonIgnoreIfNull` attribute to the `Category` field inside the `Product` model:

```cs
public class Product
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public int Price { get; set; }

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }

    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

As a result, the `Category` field does not appear in the later insertions. Which is the intended result.

[image: Result in MongoDB Compass]

---

While this fixes the problem - this might cause a potential problem when someone accidentally assigns a value to `Category` field.

```cs
var product = new Product()
{
    Price = 1000,
    CategoryId = "6207eadbef1ae25be4c731b0",
    Category = new Category { Name = "Electronics" }
};
productsCollection.InsertOne(product);
```

The unwanted `Category` field is gets inserted with the document again.

[image: Result in MongoDB Compass]

This might cause a problem when there's no validation before insertion into the database. So, I wanted to know is there a proper way to write a class for a model like this?

I have tried:

- Use `BsonIgnore` instead of `BsonIgnoreIfNull` results in `Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the serialization information for p => p.Category`
- Separate into `Product` and `ProductWithLookup` (have `Category` field) results in the same exception as above. (using approach similar to [this answer<sup>[stackoverflow.com]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56022191/7405706))

[You can view the full code here<sup>[gist.github.com]</sup>](https://gist.github.com/phwt/4dd02fc1f92baa0b4df5cafabd132c03)